# Conda/Pip Environment creation fails with azureml & adlfs/opencensus-ext-azure

Tags: python, dask, azure-machine-learning-service, opencensus, azureml-python-sdk

I am trying to create a local development environment using conda with `azureml` libraries. Following environment.yml file works fine.

```
name: cortixml_azure_env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.8.3
  - pandas
  - numpy
  - flake8
  - black
  - pip
  - pip:
    - pyarrow
    - pytest
    - rope
    - dask[dataframe,distributed]
    - azure-storage-blob
    - opencensus-ext-azure
    - azureml-core
    - azureml-pipeline-steps
    - azureml-pipeline-core
    - azureml-pipeline
    - azureml-mlflow
    - scikit-learn
    - lightgbm
    - xgboost
```

But the moment, I add [adlfs](https://pypi.org/project/adlfs/0.0.9/) under pip installable, it get stuck at "Installing pip dependencies:" for hours and finally fails. This happens for `opencensus-ext-azure` as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you paste the error message when it fails? It might contain some usefull hints.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything about your error message, from my experience, this problem usually happens because you are trying to install a library version that is not compatible with the remaining environment.

In other words, you are not specifying the version of `adlfs` that you want to install, so it tries to install the latest available and it is very likely that `adlfs` has dependencies conflicting with other packages in that file. That explains why it works well before adding and then fails when you add it.

In a nutshell, you have to create a fresh install using the environment.yml you have and then try to pip install `adlfs` yourself. It's likely that it will throw an incompatibility warning message. Use those messages to guide you on the right version of `adlfs` that will be compatible with the remaining packages.

Then finally export that working environment using:

`conda env export --name {environment-name} > environment.yml`

so you can then re-create the final environment anywhere else you need with:

`conda env create --name {environment-name} --file environment.yml`